# How to download/get multiple objects from MinIO using a single call?

Tags: minio

How can I download download/get multiple objects from MinIO using a single call of MinIO Java SDK.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is not possible to achieve this using a single call.

You'll need to perform the following steps:

- list all the files in the selected bucket using the [listObjects](https://minio-java.min.io/io/minio/MinioClient.html#listObjects-io.minio.ListObjectsArgs-) call,
- filter the objects to check if the file/files that you want are included in the bucket,
- use the [getObject](https://minio-java.min.io/io/minio/MinioClient.html#getObject-io.minio.GetObjectArgs-) call to get the information of the file (from the available files list),
- using data stream create a zip file with all the files that you require,
- start the download.